# Mongoid: How do I query for all object where the number of has_many object are > 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid4

I have a `Gift` model:

```
class Gift
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  has_many :gift_units, :inverse_of => :gift
end
```

And I have a `GiftUnit` model:

```
class GiftUnit
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  belongs_to :gift, :inverse_of => :gift_units
end
```

Some of my gifts have gift_units, but others have not. How do I query for all the gifts where `gift.gift_units.size > 0`?

Fyi: `Gift.where(:gift_units.exists => true)` does not return anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `has_many` is an assertion about the structure of `GiftUnit`, not the structure of `Gift`. When you say something like this:

```
class A
  has_many :bs
end
```

you are saying that instance of `B` have an `a_id` field whose values are `id`s for `A` instances, i.e. for any `b` which is an instance of `B`, you can say `A.find(b.a_id)` and get an instance of `A` back.

MongoDB doesn't support JOINs so anything in a `Gift.where` has to be a `Gift` field. But your `Gift`s have no `gift_units` field so `Gift.where(:gift_units.exists => true)` will never give you anything.

You could probably use aggregation through `GiftUnit` to find what you're looking for but a counter cache on your `belongs_to` relation should work better. If you had this:

```
belongs_to :gift, :inverse_of => :gift_units, :counter_cache => true
```

then you would get a `gift_units_count` field in your `Gift`s and you could:

```
Gift.where(:gift_units_count.gt => 0)
```

to find what you're looking for. You might have to add the `gift_units_count` field to `Gift` yourself, I'm finding conflicting information about this but I'm told (by a reliable source) in the comments that Mongoid4 creates the field itself.

If you're adding the counter cache to existing documents then you'll have to use [`update_counters` to initialize them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15232382/479863) before you can query on them.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Fyi, you don't need to add the gift_units_count field manually in Mongoid 4.

Comment: Thanks for the FYI. The Mongoid version that I'm currently using doesn't have `:counter_cache` (I'm doing it by hand) and some things say that you have to add the counter field by hand, some don't, and the official docs seem to be silent on the whole counter cache issue.

Comment: For anyone who follows this answer, here is a usefull link that helps you keep this implementation in sync by adding callbacks to your model on save: https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/3296

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find a solution for this problem several times already and always gave up. I just got an idea how this can be easily mimicked. It might not be a very scalable way, but it works for limited object counts. The key to this is a sentence from this [documentation](https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html) where it says:

> Class methods on models that return criteria objects are also treated like scopes, and can be chained as well.

So, get this done, you can define a class function like so:

```
def self.with_units
  ids = Gift.all.select{|g| g.gift_units.count > 0}.map(&:id)
  Gift.where(:id.in => ids)
end
```

The advantage is, that you can do all kinds of queries on the associated (GiftUnits) model and return those Gift instances, where those queries are satisfied (which was the case for me) and most importantly you can chain further queries like so:

```
Gift.with_units.where(:some_field => some_value)
```